# Always prefer [std::bind(&A::mem_fn, &obj)] to [std::bind(&A::mem_fn, obj)]?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, bind, standards

```
#include <functional>

struct A
{
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator =(const A&) = delete;

    void foo() const
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::bind(&A::foo, &a); // ok
    std::bind(&A::foo, a);  // error

    return 0;
}
```

The example seems to say:

**You should always prefer** `std::bind(&A::foo, &a);` **to** `std::bind(&A::foo, a);`.

More serious, if copying the object of `A` is costly, the latter should be avoided.

I can't think out any case that the latter is better. So, I just wonder:

**Why doesn't the C++ standard prohibit the latter?**

Comment: You should always prefer `[&](){a->foo();}` to `std::bind()`.

Comment: It depends on what the function should do, should it take a copy of `a`, or just the reference? If you want to pass the function out of `a`'s scope, and execute the function, you have to pass by copy of `a`.

Comment: +1 @Mine, this is the answer. Thanks and please turn it into the formal answer, I will take it, and hope it help more people.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the function should do:

- Should it take the the reference of `a`:

  ```
  std::bind(&A::foo, &a);
  ```

  The function takes the reference of `a`, and thus it shall be called within `a`'s scope. If `a` goes our of the scope, the reference becomes invalid, and calling the function is UB.
- Should it take a copy of `a`:

  ```
  std::bind(&A::foo, a);
  ```

  The function makes a copy of `a`, and thus can be called in in other places.

So if you want to pass the function out of a's scope, and execute the function, you have to pass by copy of `a`.